# Is it possible to trigger html5 form validation native browser message on custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

[image]

Is it possible to trigger this native validation UI on custom none-default input element like div or similar? I'd like to create custom React element with validation, but I wont to use hidden inputs or invisible input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create costume validation on input fields but not on divs: [more info](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

```js
document.getElementById('i').setCustomValidity('Test');
document.getElementById('d').setCustomValidity('Test');
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="i" />
<div id="d">asd</div>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sadly :( Thank you for answer!